# DC.js X-axis hour labels appear as thousandths

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

Using dc.js to build some charts. The localHour attribute contains numbers between 0 and 23. However, when using this on my axis, all numbers are reported as thousandths instead of the standard hour. 04 PM also appears at the origin.

How can I fix this?

```
var hourDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.hour; });
var num = hourDim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('count'));

var mainChart = dc.lineChart("#main");

mainChart
    .width(500).height(200)
    .dimension(hourDim)
    .group(num)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([0,24]))
    .yAxisLabel("Count per Hour")
```

[image: chart]

Comment: shouldn't you be setting the range as well? [some info](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales)

Comment: Not sure whether it's necessary, but adding one did not seem to make any visible change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's actually going on here is that your "hour" measurements are being interpretted as milliseconds.  Milliseconds are the default Javascript time unit if you don't specify otherwise.  Specifically, you're getting milliseconds after the Javascript zero time, which is sometime on Dec 31 1969 or Jan 1 1970 depending on timezone adjustment, and apparently starts at 4pm in your timezone.  The rest is just default formatting trying to make things look nice.

Unless you're doing other things that require the hours to be treated as timestamps, it is probably easiest to leave the hours as plain numbers, using a linear scale instead of a time scale.

If you're fine with plain old "1", "2", "3" on the axis labels, that's all you have to do.

If you want those numbers to look like hours, you need to set a [tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_tickFormat) function on the chart axis.

You *could* just do something like

```
mainChart.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,24])
                         .tickFormat(function(h){return h + ":00";})
        );
```

But that causes problems if the axis decides to put ticks at fractional values -- you'll get something that looks like 1.5:00 instead of 1:30.  You could fix that with some math and number formatting functions, but at that point you're doing enough work to make it worth using proper date-time formatting.

To get proper hour:minute axis labels, you can use a [d3 time formatting](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) function to specify the format, but you're also going to have to translate the number of hours into a valid date-time object.

```
var msPerHour = 1000*60*60;

var timeFormat = d3.time.format.utc("%H:%M");

mainChart.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,24])
                         .tickFormat(function(h){
                              return timeFormat(new Date(msPerHour*h) );
                         })
        );
```

Note that I've specified the time format function to use UTC time instead of local time, so that it treats zero as midnight.  It still thinks it's midnight, Jan 1 1970, but you're also specifying the formatting to only include hours and minutes so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: @Amelia - Is it possible to add tickFormat to x.. Or should it be added to xAxis? (I faced an error while adding to x).

Comment: You're setting it on the scale function object, unless things have changed in the latest versions.