# dc.js x-axis will not display ticks as months, shows decimals instead

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm building a bar chart using dc.js, and want the x-axis to list the 12 months of the year.

So far, I have it rendering showing the first tick as a time of day (06 PM), and all subsequent ticks as decimals (thousandths).

I saw a similar question ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392997/dc-js-x-axis-hour-labels-appear-as-thousandths#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392997/dc-js-x-axis-hour-labels-appear-as-thousandths#_=_)), but the answer involved converting milliseconds to larger units, which isn't possible with months (that I know of).

Here is my code.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.weekStart);
    d.month = d.date.getMonth();
});

var monthDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.month;});
var milesByMonth = monthDim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('miles'));
//set range for x-axis
var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;

var barChart  = dc.barChart("#myBarChart"); 
barChart
    .width(800).height(200)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 60})
    .dimension(monthDim)
    .group(milesByMonth)
    .gap(40)
    .transitionDuration(1500)
    .yAxisLabel('Miles Per Month')
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
    //.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    //.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    //.x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date(2012, 11, 31)]))
    //.round(d3.time.month.round)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the month number for your dimension key, but dates for your x domain. I would suggest always using dates as your dimension key, but using months as your group key, so that it bins by month but doesn't lose the rest of the information.

```
var milesByMonth = dateDim.group(function(d) {return d.month;}).reduceSum(dc.pluck('miles'));
barChart.dimension(dateDim)
```

You should be able to use the axis `.tickFormat()` with `d3.time.format` to get the months printing.

Something like

```
var xAxis = chart.xAxis().tickFormat(d3.time. format('%B');
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

You may also need to specify

```
chart.xUnits(d3.time.months)
```

Comment: I'm still not there.  With 
`var xAxis = barChart.xAxis().tickFormat(d3.time.format('%B'));`
added before my main barChart parameters, to which I've appended `.xUnits(d3.time.months);`
it prints 12 ticks, all labeled "December".


I also tried `var xAxis = barChart.xAxis().tickFormat(d3.time.format('%B')).ticks(d3.time.months, 12);`
which results in no labels whatsoever.

Comment: The chart doesn't render any bars, x-axis ticks, or y-axis ticks with your example data.  Now it just displays the axes themselves and the y-axis label.

I'm very new to dc, d3, and javascript in general, and have been beating my head against this for a few days.  I appreciate your patience.