# DC.js bar chart with date axis

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I would like to create a bar chart based on dates in x-axis. Labels should be displayed as month (i.e. Jan, Jan'17 - preferred). Within my data I have always first date of following months, i.e. 01Jan, 01Feb, 01Mar. I have created a chart but I am not able to make it aligned.

```
var chart   = dc.barChart("#" + el.id);
var chCategory = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d[chCategoryName];});
chValues = chCategory.group().reduceSum(
   return parseFloat(d[chValueName]);});


//set range for x-axis
var minDate = chCategory.bottom(1)[0][chCategoryName];
var maxDate = chCategory.top(1)[0][chCategoryName];
chart
  .width(800)
  .height(200)
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
  .xUnits(d3.time.months)
  .dimension(chCategory)
  .group(chValues)

  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
// .centerBar(true) //does not look better
   .controlsUseVisibility(true)
   .ordinalColors(arrColors) 
   .transitionDuration(1000)
   .margins({top: 10, left: 80, right: 5, bottom: 20})
```

[image: Chart Preview]

I have already read post: [dc.js x-axis will not display ticks as months, shows decimals instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640111/dc-js-x-axis-will-not-display-ticks-as-months-shows-decimals-instead)
but I am not able to implement it in a way that will keep correct sorting for different years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dc.js takes the domain pretty literally - the x axis stretches exactly from the beginning to the end, disregarding the width of the bars or their placement. It's a design bug.

Here are two workarounds.

#### keep bars centered and add padding

If you're using [`elasticX`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#elasticX__anchor) you can manually correct it like this:

```
chart.centerBar(true)
    .xAxisPadding(15).xAxisPaddingUnit('day')
```

If you're just setting the domain manually, that's

```
minDate = d3.time.day.offset(minDate, -15);
maxDate = d3.time.day.offset(maxDate, 15);
```

#### align the ticks to the left of bars and correct the right side of the domain

You don't say what problem you run into when you don't center the bars. [But I know the right bar can get clipped.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/792)

If you want the `elasticX` effect, you can implement it manually like this, offsetting the right side by a month ([example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/533748c2184e5fb85dc621441ab14707152f6c18/web/examples/switching-time-intervals.html#L137-L146)):

```
function calc_domain(chart) {
    var min = d3.min(chart.group().all(), function(kv) { return kv.key; }),
        max = d3.max(chart.group().all(), function(kv) { return kv.key; });
    max = d3.time.month.offset(max, 1);
    chart.x().domain([min, max]);
}
chart.on('preRender', calc_domain);
chart.on('preRedraw', calc_domain);
```

Or without `elasticX` that's just:

```
maxDate = d3.time.month.offset(maxDate, 1);
```